# Cross isinstance in Python?

Tags: python, oop

If I want to use `isinstance(var, B)` in class A's implementation, and use `isinstance(var, A)` in class B's implementation, how can I import modules properly?

For instance, if I want to implement both `a+b` and `b+a`, in which `type(a)` is `A` and `type(b)` is `B`.

In `_A.py`:

```
from mypackage._B import B
from mypackage._C import C

class A:
    def __add__(var):
        if isinstance(var, B):
            # Do something
        elif isinstance(var, C):
            # Do something
        # Do some other things
```

In `_B.py`:

```
from mypackage._A import A
from mypackage._C import C

class B:
    def __add__(var):
        if isinstance(var, A):
            # Do something
        elif isinstance(var, C):
            # Do something
        # Do some other things
```

In `_C.py`:

```
from mypackage._A import A
from mypackage._B import B

class C:
    def __add__(var):
        if isinstance(var, A):
            # Do something
        elif isinstance(var, B):
            # Do something
        # Do some other things
```

However, cross import is prohibited in Python.

Can I have some other ways to avoid this restriction?

**EDIT**: Of course, in `__init__.py`:

```
from ._A import A
from ._B import B
from ._C import C
```

Comment: You can (and probably should) do all the imports inside a top-level `__init__.py` file. You could also (but probably should not) do the imports inside the classes or methods definitions.

Comment: @DeepSpace Of course they were imported in `__init__.py`. But it can still cause error if I don't import `B` and `C` in `_A.py` and so forth.